# A variation on authoryear (aka "harvard") citation call-out style

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style, variant

What is the simplest way to make citation call-outs like this:

`(Author year: page--range)` e.g. `(Chomsky 1957: 23--24)`

or more complete:

`(Author year, volume: page--range; Author2...)` e.g. `(Knuth 1973, 3: 234--236;...)`

Edit: MWE (this is what I have tried):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author = "Author",
  title = "Title",
  publisher = "Publisher",
  series = "Series",
  year = 2017,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
word\parencite[345]{test}, 
word2\parencite{test}
word3\parencite[345--347]{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Edit 2:

It seems as if the two examples above aren't clear enough.

If the the citation is only one book (e.g. if it only one volume) then it should look like:

`(Chomsky 1957: 23)`, if it's a page range `(Chomsky 1975: 23--24)`.

*(Without the `p` or `pp` prefix.)*

If it's more than one book (e.g. if it has multiple volumes) then:

`(Knuth 1973, 3: 234)`, if it's a page range `(Knuth 1973, 3: 234--236)`

The multiple citations should be separated with `;`

Answer (score 5):

[image: aksrBiblatexYeardelim]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitevolume}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\usepackage{mwepage}
\begin{document}
Wombat   \parencite[345]{aksin},                    \par
Capybara \parencite{aristotle:physics}              \par
Duck     \pvolcite{2}[345--347]{knuth:ct:b}         \par
Mara     \parencites[1--5]{westfahl:space}[7]{ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, only the volume must be before the colon: `(Knuth 1986, 2: 345--347)`

Comment: That would be inconstistent.

Comment: Maybe, but it's the *required style*. Only the page number/range should be after the colon and before the *optional* `;`

Comment: @aksr Seems you have a god Minimal Wokring Example to ask a question just about that (*required*) inconsistency.

Comment: They don't care. I doubt they have heard of `LaTeX`.